# Difficulties with 2D avatar

Tags: c#, xna

I tried this tutorial but I get multiple error messages.

http://what-when-how.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-programmingdeveloping-for-windows-phone-7-and-xbox-360/2d-avatars-using-render-targets-xna-game-studio-4-0-programming/

I just want to draw a 2D avatar.

The name 'world' does not exist in the current context
The name 'view' does not exist in the current context
The name 'projection' does not exist in the current context 
The name 'avatarRenderer' does not exist in the current context 
The name 'avatarAnimation' does not exist in the current context
How can I fix the errors?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    RenderTarget2D renderTarget;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {  
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 512, 512, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth16);
        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1, 0.01f, 200.0f);

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        avatarRenderer.World = world;
        avatarRenderer.View = view;
        avatarRenderer.Projection = projection;
        avatarRenderer.Draw(avatarAnimation);
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied);
        spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial is supposed to be added to a basic tutorial that already draws an Avatar. E.g. [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940232.aspx).

`world`, `view` and `projection` are the transformation matrices to be used. And the `avatarRenderer` is the renderer you can retrieve from an `AvatarDescription`.